# Overlay zoomed image in node?

Tags: media, nodes

How can I implement a zoom functionality on my content nodes? Like I need to put a zoom button next to my image and clicking it brings a floating zoomed image over the page like it's done [here](http://livedemo00.template-help.com/zencart_35785/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=3&products_id=9). I'm using Drupal Commerce.

I know that it can be done through Colorbox or Lightbox2 but these modules only function in Views (or not?). How can I put this functionality on my node (product page)?

I have themed my custom `node.tpl.php` template for the product display page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) module to successfully achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved this on a node before using [Fancybox](http://drupal.org/project/fancybox) by setting up an image preset for your thumb size that opens with Fancybox. For the image to link to Fancybox you need select a Fancybox image preset under display settings for full node within your content type.

Make sure you initialize the plugin before activation using the appropriate jQuery selector.

Comment: How did you use this module? I mean how can I set my image field to be activated? I have set the path to my page as node/* but it's not working..

Comment: I have edited the above

Answer (score 0):

Magic Thumb zooms images on a product page.

The Drupal module is here:

http://www.magictoolbox.com/magicthumb/modules/drupal/

Comment: Please provide links form Drupal.org.

Comment: Yeah. And the modules there don't even work. They crash my apache server!

Comment: @NikhilMohan, why does a module *have* to come from drupal.org?

Comment: @MPD, Its because we can have a look at some familiar location for documentation, and of course its a matter of authorization. Suppose i have a module calles 'mynameis', in example.com/p/mynameis.zip. How can you provide documentation?  And what if i have a doubt on line 568? ;)

Comment: @NikhilMohan, there are plenty of modules on drupal.org that are of questionable quality, have no documentation, and are effectively abandoned.  Being on drupal.org isn't a seal of approval, and not being there doesn't make its recommendation a wrong answer.

Comment: @MPD, i accept on a 100%. shall i remove my previous comment ?

Comment: @NikhilMohan, I wouldn't worry about it.  I think it is worthwhile for posterity.  Not everyone will agree with me, and it does show both sides of the argument.